# LVM: How to inspect the content of a dm-X node?

Tags: linux, lvm

Is it possible to somehow inspect the content of LVM's dm-X (i.e. dm-0, dm-1, dm-2, dm-3, etc.) nodes?

I am asking because I urgently need to recover tons of data from my Linux system, and I think I could find it in those nodes.

(If my data would not be in the remaining visible dm-X nodes, I'd assume I would have to hire a forensic IT technician to somehow scan all hard drives.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to know what the various `/dev/dm-*` nodes correspond to, `dmsetup ls -o blkdevname` will tell you.

If you need to know which physical device(s) are involved with each `dm-X` node, `dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname` should be helpful.

If your `dmsetup` is old enough to not support the `-o blkdevname` option, you can omit it and then you will see the device numbers in `(major:minor)` form. Just run `ls -l /dev/dm-*` and you'll see the device numbers in place of the file size in `major, minor` form.

To identify the type of each mapping, `dmsetup table` might be helpful.

The "content" of each `dm-X` device node is simply the contents of the underlying device(s), viewed through the mapping. You could use `file -s /dev/dm-X` to try and identify the type (and possibly LABEL and UUID) of the filesystem within. If there's a filesystem on the device, you could simply mount it and then access it as usual - assuming that everything is working correctly. But since you mentioned the word *recover*, I suspect you have something like a failing disk complicating the situation.

So, here are some tips in case you need them in your recovery situation:

If the failing system is still running, try and grab the `dmsetup table` information before rebooting the system, if at all possible. If the system has already been rebooted, `/etc/lvm/backup` contains a backup of the current LVM configuration in a human-readable form, and `/etc/lvm/archive` contains a number of configuration backups from before each previous configuration change.

`linear` is the simplest mapping, which maps a stretch of disk blocks to and identical-sized stretch on some other disk device. LVM uses the `linear` mapping unless you explicitly specified something more advanced (like stripes or mirrors) when creating the LV.

For example, if you run `dmsetup table /dev/dm-3` and it tells you this:

```
0 293601280 linear 8:1 2048
293601280 209715200 linear 8:1 817891328
```

it means the device `dm-3` is composed of two linear mappings. First (starting from block #0 of `dm-3`) is a stretch of 293601280 blocks, mapped linearly to device 8:1 (block device, major number 8, minor 1 = `/dev/sda1`) starting from block #2048 there. The second mapping continues from block #293601280 of `dm-3`, for a stretch of 209715200 blocks, and is mapped linearly to `/dev/sda1`, starting from block #817891328.
This is what a basic LVM logical volume that has been extended once might look like when viewed as `dmsetup table`.

To copy the filesystem contained within `dm-3` to an image file or another device, you could run two `dd` commands: (or `ddrescue` if your disk is failing)

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=512 skip=2048 count=293601280 >/rescue/image
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=512 skip=817891328 count=209715200 >>/rescue/image
```

which, in a normal situation, should be exactly equivalent to simply doing

```
dd if=/dev/dm-3 bs=512 >/rescue/image
```

in the first place.